# How to scrape text from a Desktop application like skype,Notepad

Tags: python, pyautogui, pywinauto

I have need to build a function that can get the text values from the desktop application,
e.g. i need to scrape result of an output of calculator, or i need to scrape a value from desktop application such as MyCRM

Is there any way to scrape text from the desktop application?

Comment: Yes, `pyautogui` can do this, but the process is often different for each application.  You have to poke through their window structures to find the controls you need.

Comment: how can i get the control identifiyers value? for eg: i have got a control identifiyer as Static5, how can i get its value?

Comment: Actually `pywinauto` is a better choice.  Their documentation describes how to use "spy" tools to explore the window tree, and how to use the API to find a single control on a dialog.

Comment: You can try Pywinauto Recorder.
On the documentation page there are some examples to automate Calculator and Notepad in the paragraph 'Pywinauto recorder tests': https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to scrap the the values from desktop applications as well, pywinauto will be your best fit, if this is one time activity then just do it manually. if repetitive then pywinauto will be your best friend.

```
from pywinauto import Application, Desktop
import time

app = Application(backend="uia").start(r"calc.exe")
time.sleep(3)
calc = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title='Calculator')
#calc.dump_tree()
calc.child_window(title="Two", auto_id="num2Button", control_type="Button").wait('ready', 3, 1).click_input()
calc.child_window(title="Plus", auto_id="plusButton", control_type="Button").wait('ready', 3, 1).click_input()
calc.child_window(title="Four", auto_id="num4Button", control_type="Button").wait('ready', 3, 1).click_input()
calc.child_window(title="Equals", auto_id="equalButton", control_type="Button").click_input()
# calc.dump_tree()
# fetch the result
result = calc.child_window(title="Display is 6", auto_id="CalculatorResults", control_type="Text").texts()
print(result)
```

Output -

```
 ['Display is 6']
```